# How if I interact with different kubernetes clusters in different terminals sessions with out having to switch contexts all the the time?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I am testing role differences right now so I have a context for each role setup.

Terminal session *Admin*, I want to be able to use context `Admin` in one session so I can update the rules as needed.

In terminal session *User*, I want to be able to test that role via its context.

(Note: I am on EKS so roles map to IAM roles)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, I am an idiot.

Natively, there is no answer in the --help output for `kubectl`; however, there is output for this in the man page.

All one has to do is throw the  `--context` flag into their command.

However, the below-mentioned `kubectx` tool is what I use day to day now.

Comment: `Well, I am an idiot.` - well then I am too ;-) Never noticed that myself - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here are some tips for managing multiple `kubectl` contexts:

- Use [`asdf`](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) to manage multiple `kubectl` versions
- **[Set the `KUBECONFIG`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#set-the-kubeconfig-environment-variable) env var to change between multiple `kubeconfig` files**
- Use [`kube-ps1`](https://github.com/jonmosco/kube-ps1) to keep track of your current context/namespace
- Use [`kubectx` and `kubens`](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx) to change fast between clusters/namespaces
- Use aliases to combine them all together

Take a look at this article, it explains how to accomplish this: [Using different kubectl versions with multiple Kubernetes clusters](https://medium.com/@eduardobaitello/using-different-kubectl-versions-with-multiple-kubernetes-clusters-a3ad8707b87b) (Disclaimer: I wrote the mentioned article)

I also recommend this reads: [Mastering the KUBECONFIG file](https://medium.com/@ahmetb/mastering-kubeconfig-4e447aa32c75) and [Configure Access to Multiple Clusters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/)

Answer (score 2):

Now, there is kubie.
https://github.com/sbstp/kubie

it does it all.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a copy of your context file that is located under `~/.kube/config`, and in 2 different shells, point to 2 different config files using `export KUBECONFIG=/path/to/kubeconfig1` on the first and `export KUBECONFIG=/path/to/kubeconfig2` on the second. You can edit those files to have 2 different context selected.

To easily select contexts/switch between them, you can use kubectx, [as suggested by Blokje5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58608600/1005102).

Comment: This is the answer. Copy, a symlink won't do because the current context is content in the file.

Answer (score 1):

I always like [kubectx](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx) as a way to quickly switch context. If you correctly setup your contexts with the `aws-iam-authenticator`, like so:

```
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      command: aws-iam-authenticator
      args:
        - "token"
        - "-i"
        - "<cluster_id>"
        - "-r"
        - "<admin_role_arn>"
- name: kubernetes-user
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      command: aws-iam-authenticator
      args:
        - "token"
        - "-i"
        - "<cluster_id>"
        - "-r"
        - "<user_role_arn>"
```

This should allow you to easily switch contexts. (**Note:** This assumes an assume-role type situation. You can also pass `AWS_PROFILE` to the `aws-iam-authenticator` instead.)